# Does transhumanism overlap with traditional superpowers when both share the same settings?

Tags: fantasy, science-fiction, brainstorming, magic-system, magic

I always thought the superpowers/superhero genre and the supertechnolgy/futuristic genre were two different genres, but I notice that people still considered superpowers to be a part of the whole super-science or science fiction category. It doesn't matter how magical or fantastical some superpowers can be.

Speaking of magic. In my story, there are two power systems. One system is about superpowers, and the other system is about super technology. I thought superpowers would be a good stand-in for magic in my story. I wanted to replicate that classic magic vs technology narrative that some stories tell, only this time I replace magic with superpowers. My narrative in the story was a natural powers vs unnatural powers angle or something along those lines.

Then the title question came into my head. I thought maybe transhumanism and super technology would be a really broad category that would include superpowers, too. Would serum-based super soldiers overlap with mutants? If technology affects someone on a DNA or genetic level and gives them powers or abilities, would that person technically be a super-powered mutant?

Do superpowers and transhumanism overlap too much to have a story where both systems are on opposing sides?

Answer (score 2):

You are correct in the sense that superheroes/superpowers appears to be an independent subgenre straddling between fantasy and sci-fi. If this is bothering you, you can embellish either magical or technological part of your world.

"Magic vs technology" is a common conflict in superheroes subgenre. All superpowers can be classified as "magical", "technologically created" or "purely technological". What's common is that superhero genre is character-driven, and powers, for the most parts, are inseparable from individuals.

Answer (score 1):

Superpowers and transhumanism overlap, but humanity has fought over smaller differences.

One approach is to make traditionally superpowered people the society's elites, and make transhumanism represent the democratisation of superpowers that threatens the traditional order.

Depending on the scale you want to have the story play out on, it could lead to revolution in one country, or war between countries, or just be the struggle of a single transhumanist trying to achieve her goals while hunted by the authorities.

You could also reverse the sides. Transhumanism had won a long time ago, and natural-born, unregulated superpowers are considered a danger to society. Now it's the minority of natural-born superpowered individuals that need to hide their abilities and evade the system, and fight for a place in society.